# Boot camp not utilizing all cores on Mac Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, boot-camp, multi-core

I've recently inherited a MacPro2, 1 for a new development machine.  I have a decent-sized disease transmission simulation that needs to be run several thousand times.  The model is written in C# and has been optimized for multi-core systems.  I want to use boot camp to run the model on the MacPro's 2 quad-core Xenons.  There is currently a boot camp partition on the machine running XP.  However, when I boot into xp task manager only seems to recognize four of the eight cores.

Question: Can I get XP to recognize/utilize both CPU sockets in boot camp?  If so, how?

If not, would wiping the partition and installing Windows 7 in boot camp make things easier?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it Windows XP Professional? Only XP Pro is SMP-aware.

Comment: Ah, 'tis XP Home.  That would be the problem.  Thank you very much!